# How does the working of compiler differs in both cases although in both cases, n is unknown to compiler during compile time?

Tags: c, arrays, concept

**Code 1:**

```
int n;
int c[n];
scanf("%d",&n);
```

**Code 2:**

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int c[n];
```

The first one gives segmentation fault but second one works fine.

Comment: undefined behavior and hope compiler generates some code.

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both code segments use an uninitialized variable, they invoke undefined behavior  (Not to mention that you are passing in an `int` where you should be passing in an `int*`.  With undefined behavior the compiler makes no guarantees about what will happen.  It could crash as in the first case, produce no error in the second case, or [make demons fly out your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

What's happening is that in once case `n` has a value that happens to be set to a writable address and in the other it doesn't.

Comment: I half suspect that actually the call is `scanf("%d",&n);`, in which case the second would be correct (if a valid positive integer is entered).

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;     // n is uninitialized
int c[n];  // you're trying to declare an aray with an uninitialized value
```

Comment: you dint mention about scanf which is the biggest mistake here?